# Are ripple transactions reversible like how a CC chargeback works?

Tags: ripple, ripple-gateways

Does ripple take the properties of bitcoin where its irreversible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Ripple solve the double-spend problem?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7550/how-does-ripple-solve-the-double-spend-problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ripple transactions are irreversible. There are no chargebacks.